# Upgrading to latest Exchange CU vs Applying "Security Updates" for currently installed Exchange CU

Tags: exchange

**Hypothetical:** a company has Exchange 20xx installed with CU8. They are *skiddish* about applying CUs, **but** will apply monthly updates for the Windows Server operating system, and "Security Updates for CU8".

By doing this, are they missing critical security patches upstream in more current CUs (CU9-CU11)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The servicing model for Exchange 2016 and 2013 uses “cumulative updates”. A cumulative update is a complete build of the product that includes all previous updates, not an incremental patch or update.

Security update can resolve vulnerabilities in Microsoft Exchange.

What’s more, maintaining your Exchange Servers with the latest updates is the best practice.

Some relative links for your reference:

[Exchange Best Practices: Keeping Servers Updated](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/exchange-best-practices-keeping-servers-updates/)

[FAQ: In What Order Should You Install Service Packs, Update Rollups, and Cumulative Updates?](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/faq-order-install-service-packs-update-rollups-cumulative-updates/)